# Upgrade Spring Boot app (using javax.persistence) to JDK 11

Tags: java, spring, jpa, gradle, java-11

I'm in the process of converting a JDK 8 app over to JDK 11.  It builds using Gradle and uses JPA/Hibernate under the hood.  I've upgraded the necessary Gradle modules, Spring Boot is now 2.1 and it's using the Gradle 5.1 wrapper.  It uses QueryDSL JPA annotation processing to build the Q* classes off of a PostgreSQL database.

The following task in the build script generates the aformentioned classes:

```
compileJava {
    doFirst {
        generatedSourcesDir.mkdirs();
    }
    options.compilerArgs += [
            '-s', generatedSourcesDir,
    ]

//    dependsOn generateQueryDSL
}
```

And the commented-out QueryDSL generation task is:

```
task generateQueryDSL(type: JavaCompile, group: 'build', description: 'Generates the QueryDSL query types') {
    source = sourceSets.main.java
    classpath = configurations.compile + configurations.querydslapt
    options.compilerArgs = [
            "-proc:only",
            "-processor", "com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor"
    ]
    destinationDir = generatedSourcesDir
}
```

The main error I'm receiving when running the Gradle compileJava task is the following:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app-base:compileJava'.
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Entity
```

I'm using the following build dependency:

```
compile group: 'org.eclipse.persistence', name: 'javax.persistence', version: '2.2.1'
```

Which hasn't been updated since last summer.  Is there any way I can make the JavaCompile Gradle task work with JDK 11 and JPA 2.2?

**UPDATE 2/1/2019** - build.gradle for the API project as requested by a user (works with JDK 11 and Spring Boot 2.1 and Gradle 4.8, it needs significant cleanup though for Gradle 5)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-release" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.2.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: "jacoco"

jar {
    enabled = true
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-release" }
}

ext {
    generatedSourcesDir = file("${buildDir}/generated-sources")
    pojogenGeneratedDir = file("src/pojogen")
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir "src/main/java"
            srcDir pojogenGeneratedDir
            srcDir generatedSourcesDir
        }
    }
}

configurations {
    provided
    compile.extendsFrom provided
}

compileJava {
    doFirst {
        generatedSourcesDir.mkdirs();
    }
    options.compilerArgs += [
            '-s', generatedSourcesDir,
    ]
}

jar {
    enabled = true
}

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

dependencies {

    /*
        SPRING
     */

    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.1.2.RELEASE")

    // tag::tomcat[]
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.1.2.RELEASE") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-jetty:2.1.2.RELEASE"
    }
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:2.1.2.RELEASE")
    // end::tomcat[]
    // tag::actuator[]
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.1.2.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.1.2.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.1.2.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch:2.1.2.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:2.1.2.RELEASE")
    // end::actuator[]

    /*
        APACHE COMMONS
     */

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.8.1'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'

    /*
        GOOGLE GUAVA
     */

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava
    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '27.0.1-jre'

    /*
        LOGBACK
     */

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic
    testCompile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.2.3'

    /*
        MOCKITO
     */

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '2.23.4'

    /*
        JWT
     */

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt
    compile group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt', version: '0.9.1'

    /*
        MAIL
     */

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/javax.mail
    compile group: 'com.sun.mail', name: 'javax.mail', version: '1.6.2'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/javax.mail-api
    compile group: 'javax.mail', name: 'javax.mail-api', version: '1.6.2'

    /*
        SWAGGER
     */

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.9.2'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.9.2'

    /*
        PASSWORD VALIDATOR
    */

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.passay/passay
    compile group: 'org.passay', name: 'passay', version: '1.3.1'

    /*
        LOMBOK
     */

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok
    provided group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.18.4'

    /*
        Thymeleaf
     */

//    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf
//    compile group: 'org.thymeleaf', name: 'thymeleaf', version: '3.0.9.RELEASE'
//
//    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring4
//    compile group: 'org.thymeleaf', name: 'thymeleaf-spring4', version: '3.0.9.RELEASE'

    /*
        H2 (unit testing)
     */

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2
    testCompile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.4.197'

    /*
        Thumbnail tools
     */

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.coobird/thumbnailator
    compile group: 'net.coobird', name: 'thumbnailator', version: '0.4.8'

    /*
        JUNIT
     */

    testCompile("junit:junit")
}

/*
    BUILD EXCLUSIONS
 */

test {
    systemProperties 'property': 'value'
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut", "standardError"
    }
}

/*
    JaCoCo
 */
jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.7.6.201602180812"
    reportsDir = file("$buildDir/customJacocoReportDir")
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        csv.enabled false
        html.destination "${buildDir}/jacocoHtml"
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you need to add the JAR with the missing dependency.

Comment: You shouldn't need a custom task as annotation processors are detected and added automatically by Gradle. You should use the `annotationProcessor` configuration for the needed dependencies. Also when using Spring Boot you already have to needed dependencies for hibernate and JPA and you shouldn't need the additional one.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with JDK 11 by rolling back Gradle to 4.8 and rolling back Hibernate dependencies.  Ask further if interested in exact dependencies I'm using.

Comment: Can you edit the Answer and attach the build.gradle please. :) @mike-melusky

Comment: Here's my build.gradle for the API project (spring boot 2.1, jdk 11, gradle 4.8.)  I need to clean things up as other users have mentioned to make this better for gradle 5, but for the time being it works.